# Securely and automatically push to Github

Tags: git, security

I'd like to set up a `cron` job on a machine that automatically pushes code changes to GitHub at the end of the day. The easiest way to avoid having to enter a password manually would be to not have any passphrase associated with my ssh key on that machine. Would that be a security disaster? I should note, I'm not an administrator on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ssh key just for GitHub, in that way your main ssh key is not left without a passphrase. That will make it more secure.

The primary reason behind having an ssh key passphrase is if your ssh keys are compromised. If someone gains access to your private keys, they still need the passphrase to be able to use them. As long as nobody is able to access the passphrase-less ssh key that you have created just for use with GitHub, it is equally as secure as one with a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

You already trust the administrators of that machine to not fiddle with your repository, but to protect against tampering, Git offers to sign every commit with a GnuPG signature. That way you can at least be sure that there are changes that you didn't authorize.

The other decision is if you want to publish a potentially tampered repository on Github. If yes, have a dedicated SSH key on the machine and find a way to be able to remove it on the Github side if you should want to revoke access.